# combining strategy and composite pattern

Tags: design-patterns, composite, strategy-pattern

I would like to combine two design patterns in my software. I have first created a composite pattern, modeling my business problem.

[image]

Thus with this, I model the structure of my problem well, and an object tree will be created. 
I want to run some business logic on this (say *execute* function, which returns a number of elements). But this algorithm needs to be adjustable on high level. ie I want to be able to change the execute functions for all the classes shown in the picture.

I am looking for some usefull documentation and/or tips! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a Composite pattern working well with components being objects of heterogeneous types that don't share a common ancestor. You need all the components to inherit some kind of `Component` class, possibly with `Composite` and `Leaf` subclasses to specify a general behavior for leaves and nodes.

> How can A know what to inject in C/E? It only knows that it has
>   children of the 'conceptual class'

A shouldn't know it has children of the 'conceptual class'. It should only know it has `Component` children. C and E are the ones who know they are of the 'conceptual class'. Depending on your language, this double nature of C and E might be tricky to implement (no multiple inheritance, etc.)

Can you provide details on how the fact that `Class E` and `Class C` derive from a "conceptual superclass" interferes with the whole composite / execute() / strategy thing ? Without that knowledge, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me explain shortly:
1) The tree structure is to model a "house", the root is a _house_ object. It contains children of the type _roof_, _floor_, and _wall_.
2) _wall_ can be implemented in various ways: it can be modeled more general (length x width x hight, and thats all) (Class E), or it can later be implemented in more detail (the wall contains _rows_ of _bricks_, ...) (Class C)
3) Calculating the price of my house requires the strategy, because I want to be able to switch calculation methodologies. So: one strategy might count _wall_ differently then another.

Comment: If being a Wall doesn't change anything about the price calculation strategy, you can have class A pass the strategy around to its Components (`HouseComponent`s ?) regardless whether they are Walls, Floors, Roofs, etc. If being a Wall does change the price calculation logic inside the strategy, then maybe you need another pattern (Visitor ?)

Comment: The price calculation strategy for the complete house, consists of all the smaller calculations of its contained components. I imagine that in the execute of House, the list of walls will be iterated, and _execute_ will be called on each wall.
Would you still use visitor pattern, knowing this?

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to be able to extend the strategy. 
In a _general_ strategy, the price of a house is called, and it might calculate 1 dollar engineering/design cost per wall. 
But then I extend House to the class _fancyHouse_, and the strategy to _calcFancyHouse_. This calculation does the same as its ancestor, but adds 1 dollar per wall to paint it..

Comment: The visitor pattern seems to be the solution indeed. I should have googled it first :-) thanks!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 3):

Design Patterns are often combined.  I think the fact that most Pattern books show each one separately is misleading to people learning about them.

Your example is a little vague so it's a little hard to fully understand what you mean, however I think factoring out the `execute()` function into a separate interface to turn it into a Strategy and allowing that Strategy to be injected into Class A (the root of the composite) is one solution.  Class A can then inject the strategy to the other objects that are being composited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am aware its vague, the other option was explaining the business problem, which brings other trouble :-)
Ok, suppose I inject a strategy in A, and A injects its children. **How can A know what to inject in C/E?** It only knows that it has children of the 'conceptual class'. 
Now I realize my diagram is confusing. It would have been better to have an aggregation relation between A and 'Conceptual class', and remove the aggregations to C and E. 

Am I making sense?